# overwrite github repo by local files

Tags: git, github

I currently have a project which I took over from another person. After writing for a couple month, I realized that I might need to push to the github repo. However, when I pulled, there were a lot of merge conflicts. I currently only want keep what I am having on my local machine. I tried to use `git pull -X ours` but it still keeps the code from the remote repo.

Is it possible to keep all my local files as they are and overwrite what's on the github repo?

Answer (score 2):

If you really do not care about loosing the commits on the remote that conflict with yours, you can force push what you have on your local machine to the remote with:

```sh
git push -f
```

The commits on the remote that you do not have locally (for the branch you are pushing from) will get lost and your local commits will be pushed, effectively making the remote branch match your local branch.

If you don't want to loose the divergent commits on GitHub, you can create a new branch.

Comment: Thank you so much! But in order to use ```git push -f```, I think you mean I need to pull first and use ```git checkout --ours```? or am I able to push directly? Because I don't really need anything on the remote side, but only the current working version I am having locally

Comment: You can force push directly. If you really do not care about the commits that are on the remote, you only have to run `git push -f`. The commits that are on the remote and that you do not have locally (on that branch) will be lost and the remote branch will match your local branch.

Comment: Note: I edited my answer to make it clearer since, apparently, you don't care about the divergent commits on GitHub.